# Android tablet with pen input

Tags: android, tablet

I'm looking for a tablet with pen input running a recent version of Android. The main purpose would be taking notes on PDF lecture slides during lectures at university. I would not use it to listen to music, watch movies or type long texts, I have a laptop for those things.

Thus, I want:

- Android OS, preferably version 7 (manufacturers who have updated their devices quickly in the past would be a bonus)
- good input responsiveness (I don't care about the kind of pen used as long as it works reliably)
- battery life should be good
- I would prefer the OS to be as vanilla as possible (might be hard to find)
- a decent display (color temperature, contrast etc) would be nice, but not a must-have
- system performance should be smooth
- a case would also be nice to have but not mandatory

What I don't want/need:

(I've included this section because reviewers often complained about these in reviews I read)

- A good camera (I don't care if it even has one)
- 3G/LTE (I would only use WiFi)
- A good sound system (would hardly ever use it)
- good GPS (I would never use it)
- extra features such as finger print scanners, Hardware keyboards
- I also don't care much about weight and thickness, both seem to be in reasonable ranges in tablets nowadays

I don't have too strict of a budget, but I hope ~400€ would suffice (although, given good reasons, I'd be prepared to spend more, even a good amount more if it would really be worth it).

Hands-On experiences would be nice to hear, especially regarding pen input.